# Set particular environment variables during execution of a test suite

Tags: go, testing, environment-variables

I want to run a unit test fxn in Go which has to do with env vars.

At some point I go (no pun intended)

```
    for test := range tests {
        for k, v := range test.envVars {
            os.Setenv(k, v)
        }
```

Is there a way to make sure that during the test execution, the variables set by the call to `os.Setenv()` above will be the **only env vars** available to the test function?

Comment: The better way to do this would be to have the code under test not read the environment directly itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`os.Environ`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/os#Environ) to obtain the current environment and [`os.Unsetenv`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/os#Unsetenv) to unset it.

Presumably you would also need to restore those variables after the test completes, for which you could use a [subtest](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks) per environment with [`(*testing.T).Cleanup`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Cleanup) (https://play.golang.org/p/A5HGZwWm-NS):

```golang
    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            // NOTE: do NOT call t.Parallel in this subtest or its parent,
            // or the environment WILL be corrupted.
            //
            // (However, *subtests of* t may be run in parallel.)

            prevEnv := os.Environ()
            for _, entry := range prevEnv {
                parts := strings.SplitN(entry, "=", 2)
                os.Unsetenv(parts[0])
            }
            for k, v := range tc.envVars {
                os.Setenv(k, v)
            }
            t.Cleanup(func() {
                for k := range tc.envVars {
                    os.Unsetenv(k)
                }
                for _, entry := range prevEnv {
                    parts := strings.SplitN(entry, "=", 2)
                    os.Setenv(parts[0], parts[1])
                }
            })

            …
        })
    }
```

---

Also note that Go 1.17 adds the [`(*testing.T).Setenv`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/testing@master#T.Setenv) method, which cleans up the modification automatically. However, there is not yet a corresponding `(*testing.T).Unsetenv`.

---

If you want to be able to run tests in parallel, you could instead use subtests with `os/exec` and the `-test.run` flag to re-exec the particular subtest as a subprocess of the main test process, with its own distinct environment.

Comment: However, I guess bringing (setting) the envs back is not mandatory (given that only the specific OS system process running the tests will be affected by this action (as long as I am ok with it)

Comment: That is correct — although if you want it to apply to all tests in the entire process, it may be clearer for future maintainers (including yourself!) to unset the variables within a [`TestMain`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Main) rather than an individual test function.